# Multi-domains I/O n CPU restrictions via nginx vps

Tags: nginx, vps

on shared hosting you have limiation on how many Disk I/O your site will use , how much ram you will use etc.

On VPS ubuntu with nginx with many sites , is it possible to do that? 
for example i want one site to get 80% of vps' recourses (CPU/ram/ I/O) and the rest sites the rest 20%.

I tried to find something on google but no luck,

Anyone knows any tutorial about this.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know CloudLinux can do that. I think its not so easy possible, maybe if you make an own VPS and limit the resources but thats not easy and can be expensive.